# Definition of a specific linear transformation being applied to create a change of variable matrix - Example - Lin Alg by Friedberg

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I have a question about a specific example of a linear transformation used to define a change of coordinate matrix. The example comes from *Linear Algebra by Friedberg, Insel, et.al*. The following is a screenshot of the example:

[image]

[image]

My question pertains to what linear transformation ,$T$, are they using to define the basis $\beta'$? The trouble began in trying to figure out how $T(-2,1) = -(2,1) = (2,-1)$ and how this applies to the rotation of the axis that the authors are trying to accomplish. Would someone be able to explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you understand what they are trying to achieve: we are looking for a linear transformation $T$ which reflects points of $\Bbb R^2$ on the line $y=2x$. We will completely know a linear transformation, if we know it's action on a basis of $\Bbb R^2$. You can check independently, that the vectors

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\2 
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}-2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

form a basis for $\Bbb R^2. $So we will know $T$ if we know it's action on this basis. Call this basis $\beta'$. Why are we choosing this basis? This is because it's easy to see $T$'s action on $\beta'$. Since $T$ reflects points on the line $y = 2x$, you can easily check that
$$T \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\2 \end{bmatrix}$$

this is because the point $(1,2)$ lies on the line of reflection. Similarly using geometric arguments, you can show that $T(-2,1) = (2,-1)$. Therefore the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $\beta'$ is $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -2 \\2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Since we are used to dealing with vectors in the usual canonical basis, we simply do a change of basis and find the corresponding matrix of $T$ with respect to the usual basis.

Comment: I think I have the idea of what is happening. I'll explain it here to make sure the reasoning is correct. So our objective is to have a transformation that reflects in the line $y = 2x$. We used the basis $\beta'$ since it makes our lives easier, but this is in essence one of many bases for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. As vectors $T(1,2) = (1,2)$ because this is the line we are reflecting through, but now $T(-2,1) = (2, -1)$ because we are reflecting which means we take the opposite direction that the vector is oriented, which is where the minus sign comes into play. This correct in it's make up?

Comment: yes you are correct

Comment: Nice. Thanks for your help